# Regular expression to extract comma separated values?

Tags: regex, minify, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am trying to read values from a csv file and then store the values into attributes using ExtractText processor. The file contains only one line, which has 5 values separated by comma. Here is the content of my file:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test, com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar, root, root
```

I have manually added 5 properties in the ExtractText processor:-

```
DatabaseConnectionURL
DatabaseDriverClass
DatabaseDriverLocation
DatabaseUser
Password
```

Now, I want regular expressions for the above 5 attributes that I have defined in the ExtractText processor so that they get the following value:-

```
DatabaseConnectionURL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
DatabaseDriverClass = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DatabaseDriverLocation = C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar
DatabaseUser = root
Password = root
```

Can you please provide me the regular expression for the above 5 attributes?

Comment: The regex would be `^([^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*)){4}` (demo: https://regex101.com/r/AHK23W/1), or more verbosely ^([^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*)) (demo: https://regex101.com/r/AHK23W/2) I don't know how to make it work with apache nif -s `ExtractText` though.

Comment: @TamasRev thanx. Your given regex works but can you tell me regex that fetches only the 3rd value from the csv file.

Comment: @TamasRev below is the content of the file:-
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test, com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar, root, root

So, basically I want a regex that fetches only the third value i.e. C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar

Comment: Luckily, it's not a fully-fledged csv file. That would be way more complicated to parse. RFC 4180 explains it all: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

So, back selecting only the 3rd value: you can remove the not necesary parentheses, and the rest of the pattern that comes after the 3rd element. So with this regex: `^[^,]*(?:\s*,\s*[^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))\s*,\s*` the 3rd element will be in group 1. Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/AHK23W/3

Comment: Thanx a lot @TamasRev

Comment: First Value  : ^([^,]*)(?:\s*)
Second Value : ^[^,]*(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))\s*,\s*
Third Value  : ^[^,]*(?:\s*,\s*[^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))\s*,\s*
Fourth Value : ^[^,]*(?:\s*,\s*[^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*[^,]*)(?:\s*,\s*([^,]*))\s*,\s*

To be added: (?:\s*,\s*[^,]*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rishab,

You the ExtractText processor with the following regular expression to capture lines.

```
ExtractedData:(^.*$)
```

Then use updateAttribute with `getDelimitedField()` expression as demonstrated below to assign values to flow file attributes.

```
DatabaseConnectionURL:${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(1)}

DatabaseDriverClass:${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(2)}

DatabaseDriverLocation:${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(3)}

DatabaseUser:${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(4)}

Password:${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(5)}
```

`getDelimitedField()` "Parses the Subject as a delimited line of text and returns just a single field from that delimited text." and can be used on any configuration property that supports NiFi's expression language. For detailed `getDelimitedField()` explanation, view the NiFi Expression Language guide.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield

Hope this solution helps solve your problem.

Don't forget to accept if it worked and let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You always come up with the best solution. However, I have an issue. 
   
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746815/dbcpconnectionpool-service-not-accepting-values-stored-in-attributes

Comment: Thank you. Answered that too:)