# 'DBCPConnectionPool' Service Not accepting values stored in attributes

Tags: minify, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

Following are the combination of processors that I am using:-

```
GetFile + SplitText + ExtractText + UpdateAttribute + ExecuteSQL + ConvertAvroToJson + PutFile
```

Basically,I have a properties file which contains 5 comma separated values that are required by the 'DBCPConnectionPool' controller service to establish connection with the database. Here is the content of my properties file:-

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test,com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar,root,root
```

Now, I am extracting the values from this properties file and storing them in manually created properties.I am using this regex to store that values into attributes using ExtractText.

```
ExtractedData: (.*)
```

Then use updateAttribute processor to manually add 5 properties and get their values from the properties file like below:

```
connectionURL  : ${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(1)}
driverClass    : ${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(2)}
driverLocation : ${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(3)}
user           : ${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(4)}
password       : ${ExtractedData:getDelimitedField(5)}
```

So, by now the attributes have got their values from the properties file and thus following values stored in them:

```
connectionURL  : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
driverClass    : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
driverLocation : C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector.jar
user           : root
password       : root
```

Finally, Here is what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to use these above 5 attributes in the DBCPConnectionPool Controller Service like this:

```
 Database Connection URL     : ${connectionURL}
 Database Driver Class       : ${driverClass}
 Database Driver Location(s) : ${driverLocation}
 Database User               : ${user}
 Password                    : ${password}
```

But I am unable to establish the connection and I am getting the error 'Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory'. It seems that the controller service is unable to read the value from the attributes. How can I pass a flowfile attribute to a controller service?

Comment: Links for the images: 
-->https://ibb.co/nf8J7H
-->https://ibb.co/hvQy7H
-->https://ibb.co/dpGS1c
-->https://ibb.co/buJJ7H
-->https://ibb.co/cMiUEx
-->https://ibb.co/n8vy7H
-->https://ibb.co/d8ZrSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'DBCPConnectionPool' Service Not accepting values stored in attributes`

That's not an issue. This is a feature )

Connection to the database established on controller service start and not on flow file passing to the dbcp processor.

Comment: Does that mean 'DBCPConnectionPool' Service does not accept values stored in attributes

Comment: That's right. You can't use flow file attributes in `DBCPConnectionPool Service` connection parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Actually I am looking for a way where I can specify **DBCPConnectionPool Service** connection parameters in a file and then use those connection parameters present  in the file to establish a connection to the database. Basically, I am looking for a work-around where I can have only one **Database Connection Pooling Service** and the connection parameters could be fetched dynamically. Could you suggest me anything?

Comment: @RishabPrasad, how often connection parameters are changed? how many unique connections do you have? is it possible that two flow files that processed by the same processor in parallel threads should be inserted in two different databases?

Comment: Basically, our work is data ingestion. We need to extract data from multiple databases(MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DERBY etc.) and then store it to HDFS. So every time the source database changes, we manually need to change the parameters of controller service. We want to automate this. We want to put all the parameters in a property file from which the DBCPConnectionPool controller service will fetch its parameters value. We will have multiple properties file for each database such that we only need to change the input property file whenever there is a change in the source database

Comment: `1:` the only way to use parameters from properties file in standard DBCPConnectionPool - `nifi.variable.registry.properties` parameter in `nifi.properties` that could reference to property file with connection parameters. but nifi will load it only once during startup. `2:` you can write your own processor that will open/close connection dynamically for every flow file...

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: I understand that we can't use flow file attributes in DBCPConnectionPool Service connection parameters because the connection to the database is being established at the time of service enable i.e. even before the processors have started to run.So my question here is, why does Nifi establishes the connection even before any other processor starts running?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool *connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required.* means that connection established before you know that connection required. write script or custom processor to establish connections dynamically.